# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (p_n)^{-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, convergence-divergence

How to determine the convergence of 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (p_n)^{-n},
$$
where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime?

Comment: If you write the sum as 1/p_1 + ∑ (p_n)^-n (the sum being over n from 2 to infinity) then it is obviously less than 1/2 + ∑ (p_n)^-2 , and since the prime number set is a proper subset of the natural number set , the sum is obviously less than 1/2 + ζ(2) , whence convergent.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A093358

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p_n^n} = \dfrac12 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p_n^n} \leq \dfrac12 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac1{p_n^2} \leq \dfrac12 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \dfrac1{n^2} = \dfrac12  + \dfrac{\pi^2}6 - 1 = \dfrac{\pi^2}6 - \dfrac12$$